# What do the different colors mean in Google timeline?

Tags: google-maps

What do the different color lines on my timeline stand for? Blue, light blue, white, etc. I have looked everywhere that I can think of with no luck finding answers. I have tried googling it and asking forums but no one has had an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If indeed for Maps:

> It seems there are five colors:
>   light blue, cyan, dark blue, red and purple.....
>   Light Blue: Move or walking
>   Cyan: Moving by Transportation with no engine and not require lot of manpower, like cycling, wheelchair, skateboard
>   Dark Blue: Moving by Transportation with engine on ground or water, like driving, on a boat, subway, bus......
>   Red: Moving with lot of power, like running, hiking.....
>   Purple: On a plane

[Kun Luo](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/maps/Wqdy8_XVWog/kys_PsEPCAAJ).

Maybe essentially a measure of speed.